# matlab fast sliding windows with predefined overlap (im2col 'sliding' matlab)

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, matlab

I need to get local pixel histograms from a size of 10x10 sliding windows from an image of size NxN (N>>10).

I am using the follwing code to obtain the sliding windows.

```
       B = im2col(inputImage, [10, 10],'sliding');
```

But according to this code I cannot determine the overlap between two local windows. 
How can I get local histograms from image with a sliding window of size mxm and half overlap between two sliding windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IM2COL function always generates sliding windows with `[n-1,m-1]` overlap (i.e 1 pixel shifting). Perhaps you can call IM2COL as is, and then discard columns you dont want. Remember that the sliding windows are generated by traversing the matrix in a column-order manner.

---

A quick search revealed a custom [`im2colstep`](http://code.google.com/p/retarget-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/Matlab/Saliency/k-svd/ksvdbox13/private/im2colstep.m) function, implemented as a [MEX-file](http://code.google.com/p/retarget-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/Matlab/Saliency/k-svd/ksvdbox13/private/im2colstep.c). In your case, you would call it as:

```
cols = im2colstep(inputImage, [10 10], [5 5]);
```

The function is part of [KSVD-Box](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~ronrubin/software.html) package, "available for free for academic and personal use" according to the author.